# Syntax error , unexpected Declare_sym

Tags: mysql

This is my Mysql code ,
It gives a
 syntax error  unexpected Declare_sym

```
  delimiter @ 
  create procedure StudentUpsert
  (in in_regno int ,
  in in_fNM varchar(50),
  in in_mNM varchar(50),
  in in_lNM varchar(50),

  begin 
  declare  regno_Count int ; 
  select Count(*) into regno_Count
  fro students_info 
  if regno_Count > 0 then

   update students_info
   set firstname = in_fNM,
   middlename = in_mNM,
   lastname = in_lNM,
   where regno = in_regno ;
   else
   insert into students_info
   values (in_regno , in_fNM , in_mNM ,in_lNM );
   end if ;
   end @
   delimiter ;
   call StudentUpsert(9, 'ABC','NA','XYZ');
```

please help
 syntax error  unexpected Declare_sym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `Declare_sym` in your posted query but your SQL code do have syntax error as pointed below. Not sure if those are just typo while posting the question

```
 select Count(*) into regno_Count
 fro students_info 
  ^...... should be *from*

   update students_info
   set firstname = in_fNM,
   middlename = in_mNM,
   lastname = in_lNM,   <----- remove this extra *,* here
   where regno = in_regno ;
```

Change your procedure body to be like below

```
  delimiter @ 
  create procedure StudentUpsert
  (in in_regno int ,
  in in_fNM varchar(50),
  in in_mNM varchar(50),
  in in_lNM varchar(50))
  begin 

  declare  regno_Count int ; 
  select Count(*) into regno_Count
  from students_info;

  if regno_Count > 0 then
   update students_info
   set firstname = in_fNM,
   middlename = in_mNM,
   lastname = in_lNM
   where regno = in_regno ;
   else
   insert into students_info
   values (in_regno , in_fNM , in_mNM , in_lNM);
   end if;
   end@
```

Comment: thnx @Rahul but syntax error unexpected Declare_sym is still there